# c# winform datagridview cell click to TabControl Page

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabs, datagridviewcolumn

i want to implement a function that can

> click on the datagridview's cell/columns than will switch to Tab page

any idea on it ?

like these picture

[pic one is the total result on Tab 1 and Tab2, when i click on cell/column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enEl2.jpg)

[switch to Tab1 or Tab2 to see the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPrEX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if you are clicking on needed column
        // and focus the tab
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
    }
```